# Cannot access tuple elements through the for in range loop

Tags: python

I write a small python program
Use for in range loop to combine the tuple content of subjects and score
Displayed on print
I hope to achieve the following effects

```py
Chinese score: 85 points
Math score: 79 points
English score: 93 points
```

But instead this error result

```py
Chinese score:  points 85
Math score:  points 79
English score:  points 93
```

Each of its Chinese, Mathematics, and English are printed out three times wrongly
Then the score is printed on the outside of the score
I hope everyone can help
How to use the for in range loop to combine the contents of the tuple
How about displaying in print?
My code:

```py
subjects=["Chinese scores: points","Mathematics scores: points","English scores: points"]
score=["85","79","93"]
for subs in range(len(subjects)):
   for scs in range(len(score)):
    print(subjects[subs],score[scs])
```

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

In you code, nested for loop means each subject with three score and you already set "score: points" before the number of score.

```py
subjects=["Chinese","Mathematics","English"]
score=["85","79","93"]
for index in range(len(subjects)):
    print(f'{subjects[index]} score: {score[index]} points')
```

```py
Chinese score: 85 points
Mathematics score: 79 points
English score: 93 points
```

Maybe you can use zip for it,

```py
subjects = ["Chinese","Mathematics","English"]
scores = [85, 79, 93]
for subject, score in zip(subjects, scores):
    print(f'{subject} score: {score} points')
```

```py
Chinese score: 85 points
Mathematics score: 79 points
English score: 93 points
```